# What is views.py for?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-admin

I am currently learning how to build a backend and I have only used the views.py file to set up Django Rest Framework. Almost everything is happening in my models.py or admin.py file.

Is that a problem? What even is views.py for?

I should add that I will be using Angular for the frontend later!

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: views.py is like controller to connect your db data with HTML pages.

Answer (score 0):

The convention is you that you write the logic that connects to your db in views.py but then you can define the view anywhere you prefer even inside the models.py so long as you're able to call it when needed.
For more, check.
[this here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial01/)

Answer (score 0):

Django works on MVC model which enables to structure data and template individually.
In django we retrieves the data from the models in views and render that data with a template. So view processes the data with our logic and give that data to template.